# Drawing a colored rectangle in a macOS app (Swift)

Tags: xcode, cocoa, calayer, nsview, cgrect

Just started to learn Swift. I’ve created a macOS app project using the `Xcode 6 Beta 6`. Now I want to use the `ViewController.swift` to draw a colored rectangle (for testing purposes) in the apps main view (a `NSWindow` within the `Main.storyboard`).

I’ve tried this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   let myRect = NSView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))
   myRect!.backgroundColor = NSColor.redColor().CGColor // app crashes here
   self.view.addSubview(myRect)
}
```

The app crashed in the third line: `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION`.

Not only Swift but also Xcode is totally new to me and I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s been a while since I asked this question but I noticed that it got a lot of views recently, so providing an actual answer (**Swift 4.2**) might be helpful for a bunch of people:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   let myFrame = NSRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 200.0, height: 200.0)
   let myRect = NSView(frame: myFrame)
   myRect.backgroundColor = NSColor.red
   self.view.addSubview(myRect)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the code in ViewDidAppear instead...

you are trying to draw a rectangle on a view which hasn't been displayed yet.

Answer (score 1):

I think you missed to add the following before setting the background color:

```
theRectangle.wantsLayer = true
```